# webgl, texture becomes fuzzy

Tags: webgl

i'm trying to load image on webgl by texture, the detail steps is:

1. after loaded image ,create positions and bind positionBuffer:

```
...
       const positions = [                    // here width is viewport width, and height calculted by height = naturalHeight / naturalWidth * width;
            -width / 2, -height / 2, 0.0,
            width / 2, -height / 2, 0.0,
            width / 2, height / 2, 0.0,
            -width / 2, height / 2, 0.0,
        ]
...
```

2. create textureCoordinates and bind textureCoordBuffer
3. create indices( define which vertexes combines a plane ) and bind indexBuffer
4. create projectionMatrix ,modelViewMatrix, pull out the positions from the positionbuffer into the vertexPosition attribute, pull out the texture coordinates from the texture coordinate buffer into the textureCoord attribute
5. pass projectionMatrix,modelViewMatrix by `gl.uniformMatrix4fv`
6. bindTexture:

```
       gl.pixelStorei(gl.UNPACK_FLIP_Y_WEBGL, 1);
        const level = 0;
        const internalFormat = gl.RGBA;
        const srcFormat = gl.RGBA;
        const srcType = gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE;
        const texture = gl.createTexture();
        gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, texture);
        gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, level, internalFormat, srcFormat, srcType, image);

       gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_S, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
       gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_T, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
       gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.LINEAR );
       gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER,gl.LINEAR );
```

7. last step is active texture0,bindTexture,bound the texture to texture unit 0, and  `gl.drawElements(gl.TRIANGLES, vertexCount, type, offset);`

After these steps, the result on the screen just looks compressed, the image becomes fuzzy and full of sawtooth.
What could i do to solve this problem ?

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot?

Comment: i found the anwser, dpr result in this, and finally i change the` canvas.width = viewWidth * dpr` fix that